# PHP site - as service - how to separate it as modules or addins with easy integration

Tags: php, service, module, add-in

i am creating a php website as a service. My customers pay me annual fee and they will use this service during this time.

My question: I want to provide several features. And some customers needs only certain features. Some needs custom made features. So how to separate it as modules or addins when coding, keeping it simple for integration to the site.

Please guide me.

Example site: Shiftcode.com
Check their gpt sites admin panel.

thanku

Comment: Have worked with Object Oriented Programming before?

Comment: Personally that's what I'd recommend, but OOP isn't just about using classes. You should change the way you look at your application in general and code each functionality as a separate method/function.Also you should maintain that the classes can operate on their own as intendant pieces of code so you can easily deploy them to other places. I highly recommend reading [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-PHP-Concepts-Techniques-Code/dp/1593270771)

Comment: thanku. I will check that. Can u plz tell me what you mean by "maintain that the classes can operate on their own as intendant pieces of code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at http://www.symfony-project.org/, a very good framework for PHP development. It has a nice routing feature that can fit your needs. And you will gain unit test framework and a lot of other things.

Comment: thanku. I have tried using CodeIgniter once. Do i have to use an existing framework or make my own framework for this ?

Comment: You can always write your own code :) But learning a framework, you can reuse your new knowledge on other projects, and of course you avoid time spending writing trivial code that always wraps your business behaviour.

Comment: i am not very good in php. but i will make use of a framework like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

before decide about developing such complex application, have a look at existing ones like [WordPress Multisite/Network](http://wpcandy.com/presents/an-introduction-to-wordpress-multisite)

Comment: with WordPress multisite you just need develop your custom plugins and activate them for certain users...

Comment: thanku. I am not interested in creating it as a wordpress site. Instead a complete PHP site.

Comment: I mean you can use WordPress as start point of your PHP website

Comment: thanku. But wordpress is something that i dont like to use.